# MongoDB - Next.js I can't map the data

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am getting data from database to map this data in a page:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../utils/mongodb";
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/client'


export default async (req, res) => {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
  const session = await getSession({ req });

   const companies = await db
    .collection("companies")
    .find({ "owner.$id": session.id })
    .sort({ metacritic: -1 })
    .limit(20)
    .toArray();

    res.json(companies)
};
```

I want to **set state** and **map** this data but it gives an error,

```
const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([])

fetch('../api/getcompanies')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCompanies(data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        alert('fetch failed');
      });
```

**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name, number}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Answer (score 0):

What does a sample document look like?
What is the setCompanies() function?

Comment: It is getting an Object like data[0].name, but in state (companies) it says undefined. setCompanies() is a React function that sets a state, in my question it is companies.